# IBM Integration Bus - TCP Nodes - Request Response Mismatch

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a sample message flow where a TCP Output Node communicates to an external system and receives response to a TCP Client receive node. My issue is, is there a way whether I can ensure that the TCP request and TCP response are correctly mapped and processed. We have observed in certain circumstances few request and responses getting mismatched. I understand there is a **$LocalEnvironment/Destination/TCPIP/Output/Id** property in the TCP IP Client Output Node and **$LocalEnvironment/TCPIP/Receive/Id** in the TCP IP Client receive Node. Should these be same for a single request and response? Should I write an ESQL check to ensure the request and response are correlated? Any advice would be very much helpful.

[image]

Comment: Have you read the documentation? (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/integration-bus/9.0.0?topic=messages-tcpip-nodes).

Comment: I have Kimber, it discusses the problem rather how to solve it. (or my understanding might be less), hence looking forward to some expert advice.